# convert elements after xml to array

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML with products and I converted it to Array from XML using this function http://www.bin-co.com/php/scripts/xml2array/
I have a problem when I have only one attribute in XML file and I'm trying to convert first array into multidimensional.

```
[attributes] => Array
    (
        [attribute] => Array
            (
                [name] => 44
                [quantity] => 1
                [availability] => 1
            )

    )
```

to

```
    [attributes] => Array
        (
            [attribute] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => 40
                            [quantity] => 1
                            [availability] => 1
                        )
                )
        )
```

I need a multidimensional array for a loop

```
foreach($products["attributes"]["attribute"] as $attr) {
    echo $attr["name"]
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <id>1006</id>
        <sku>360116 05</sku>
        <attributes>
            <attribute>
                <name>44</name>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
                <availability>1</availability>
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>2501</id>
        <sku>AQ4040</sku>
        <attributes>
            <attribute>
                <name>42.5</name>
                <quantity>13</quantity>
                <availability>2</availability>
            </attribute>
            <attribute>
                <name>44</name>
                <quantity>18</quantity>
                <availability>2</availability>
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
    </product>
</products>
```

Comment: Try this in your foreach: $products["attributes"]["attribute"][0]

Comment: Can you show the XML your trying to convert?

Comment: @TBowm it wont help because some products have more attributes.

Comment: @NigelRen I just added a part of XML

Answer (score 0):

May b you get some solution from here https://www.php.net/xml_parse_into_struct didn't try but hope it will help. Refer Example #3 parsemoldb.php on it, similar to your function file.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get at the items in this sort of structure, it could be simpler to use SimpleXML.  The following code access the data very simply.

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

$xmlText = <<< XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <id>1006</id>
        <sku>360116 05</sku>
        <attributes>
            <attribute>
                <name>44</name>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
                <availability>1</availability>
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>2501</id>
        <sku>AQ4040</sku>
        <attributes>
            <attribute>
                <name>42.5</name>
                <quantity>13</quantity>
                <availability>2</availability>
            </attribute>
            <attribute>
                <name>44</name>
                <quantity>18</quantity>
                <availability>2</availability>
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
    </product>
</products>
XML;

$doc = simplexml_load_string($xmlText);

foreach ( $doc->product as $product)   {
   echo "Product id=".$product->id.",";
   foreach ( $product->attributes->attribute as $attribute){
       echo "name:".$attribute->name.",";
   }
   echo "\n";
}

echo "Complete";
```

The output of which is...

```
Product id=1006,name:44,
Product id=2501,name:42.5,name:44,
Complete
```

When loaded using simple_xml_ you can then access sub-elements as though they are attributes of the element above, so `$product->attributes->attribute` uses each product and then picks out the attributes element and then each attribute element within that.
To load from a file, use simplexml_load_file().

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you might be looking for:

```
foreach($products["attributes"] as $product) {
    foreach($product["attribute"] as $attr) {
        echo $attr["name"]
    }
}
```